# undefined reference to '__GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE'

Tags: c, gcc

I have added -fno-pie in the CFLAGS, but it still shows this error:

```
ld -melf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin start.o kernel.o console.o utils.o
kernel.o: In function `_main':
kernel.C:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `__GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
makefile:30: recipe for target 'kernel.bin' failed
make: *** [kernel.bin] Error 1
```

The make file is shown below:

```
GCC_OPTIONS = -m32 -fno-pie -nostdlib -fno-builtin -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fleading-underscore -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables

all: kernel.bin

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.bin

# ==== KERNEL ENTRY POINT ====

start.o: start.asm
    nasm -f aout -o start.o start.asm

# ==== UTILITIES ====

utils.o: utils.H utils.C
    gcc $(GCC_OPTIONS) -c -o utils.o utils.C

# ==== DEVICES ====

console.o: console.H console.C
    gcc $(GCC_OPTIONS) -c -o console.o console.C

# ==== KERNEL MAIN FILE ====

kernel.o: kernel.C
    gcc $(GCC_OPTIONS) -c -o kernel.o kernel.C


kernel.bin: start.o kernel.o console.o utils.o linker.ld
    ld -melf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin start.o kernel.o console.o utils.o
```

May I ask help for this question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you make clean and then make all, so you can see the commands, is it *actually* passing -fno-pie to gcc?

Comment: yes, but that is the common way to solve the problem. For my make file, this doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

First thing that striked me was "why you're using .C (capitalized) extension for .c file, it's reserved for C++?".
So I made a test:

```
# with `-fno-rtti'
$ export CFLAGS1="-m32 -fno-pie -nostdlib -fno-builtin -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-stack-protector -fleading-underscore -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables"
# without `-fno-rtti'
$ export CFLAGS2="-m32 -fno-pie -nostdlib -fno-builtin -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-exceptions  -fno-stack-protector -fleading-underscore -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables"
$ mv kernel.C kernel1.C
$ cp kernel.C kernel2.c
$ gcc $CFLAGS1 -c -o kernel1.C.o kernel1.C

$ gcc $CFLAGS1 -c -o kernel2.c.o kernel2.c
cc1: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
$ gcc $CFLAGS2 -c -o kernel2.c.o kernel2.c
```

So I bet if you decapitalize your extensions form `.C` into `.c` and `.H` into `.h` you'll get better results.
GCC is fussy in this regard. If you want C code use **gcc** and `.c` extension, if you want C++ use **g++** and `.C` or `.cc` or `.cpp` or `.cxx`.

---

Also I think you should use `gcc` instead of `ld` as link command. Ld is usually "stupid" and `gcc` knows better.

---

PS. Let me know which one is/is not right. If wrong I will remove answer to not confuse audience.